# I want to redirect root and sub folders to different pages

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a root domain to another domain. The problem is, I also want to keep the subfolders.

For example: redirect `domain/subfolder` to `anotherdomain/subfolder`.

Comment: I see someone just gave -1 to the question. Can't anybody answer this ?

Comment: Let me find my magic wand quickly. Have you not tried anything? See: [Help Center > Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have tried many times before, I also tried RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/webpage/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,L]

But its adding /webpage to every sub directory redirect

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what you have tried *in the question itself*, and explain exactly what you want to have happen.

Comment: Hello Ed, Mike have already given the solution below and that works really great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your question is not specific, I can only assume you need the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if a directory is being requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

# If so, redirect the request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

**Update** - Try this, based on the requirement in your comment.

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.kaysellers.com/webpage/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.kaysellers.com/$1 [R,L]
```

You may change the `R` flag to `R=301` to make it permanent, if you would like it to be.

---

<sub>**Note:** Please try and do your own homework in future. You should ask questions on StackOverflow when you have, at the very least, made an attempt to do what you want to do and not had any luck.</sub>

Comment: I want you to visit kaydev.org it will redirect you to kaysellers.com/webpage/ 

also when you visit kaydev.org/test it will redirect you to kaysellers.com/webpage/test however I want it to redirect it to kaysellers.com/test